# How do I get the current iframe offset from within the iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, offset

I expect security restrictions (cross-site scripting) will prevent me from doing this, but I thought asking wouldn't hurt. I'm working on a page that may be embedded within another page from a different domain. I don't know anything about the iframe, except I could predict part of the src attribute. I can detect "if" it's embedded, but I really need to know the offset at which it's embedded.

I'm doing some position calculations within my page (that in this case is embedded in an iframe). It works great whether or not it's embedded in all current browsers but gives me problems in IE 7. For some reason the offset jQuery gives me in IE 7 is off by the exact amount of the embedded iframe offset. I could compensate for it in this case, if I could get the offset.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is going to be possible. A better solution would be to figure out exactly why IE7 is giving you this problem and if there is a solution to THAT, as it is more than likely going to be an easier/cleaner route to take.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. That's probably good advice, but it may be out of my control, as it appears this is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JavaScript.

Parent Frame

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe src="childFrame.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Child Frame

```
<html>
<body>
   Child Frame
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.parentWindow.document.body.innerHTML);
</script>
</html>
```

The key bit is here "document.parentWindow.document.body". Now you have the parent body you can access the HTML and get any properties you need.

The other way round you can use the Sandbox attribute on the Iframe. Check out the link below. This attribute is not recommended for production code.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: This doesn't work cross-origin, does it?